# how to get a span class to come up below the label

Tags: html, css, forms

So i am creating basic forms right now and i am having an issue with this little thing that i want someone else to look at for me. Been trying this thing for hours now.

I have a span class that i want to come up below the label. As of right now, the span comes side by side as the label and i want it below the label. Here is my html/css

CSS:

```
fieldset { width: 900px; }
input[type=text], select, textarea{width: 100%; }
span .half {float: left; width: 48%; padding: 1%; }
.half { float: left; width: 48%; padding: 1%; }
.full { clear: both; width: 100%; padding: 1%; }
.clear { clear: both; }
.right { text-align: right; }
/*little line breaks that separte sections*/
.generalinfo { padding-top: 10px;}
/* Reset CSS */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
    background: #DCDDDF url(http://pixelmatter.co/img/tweed_@2X.png);
    color: #000;
    font: 14px Arial;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
h1{ font-size:28px;text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom: 2px;}
h2{ font-size:26px;}
h3{ font-size:18px;}
h4{ font-size:16px;}
h5{ font-size:14px;}
h6{ font-size:12px;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ color:#34495e;}
small{ font-size:10px;}
b, strong{ font-weight:bold;}
a{ text-decoration: none; }
a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.alignleft { float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
.alignright { float: right; margin-left: 15px; }
.clearfix:after,
form:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}


::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #808488;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #808488;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #808488;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #808488;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="half">
       <label for="abc">abc</label>
         <span class="half">abcabc</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the css you could...

```
label{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}
```

and take that class of the span and give it the styles

```
span{
 float:left;
 width:100%;
}
```

So the point of this is really just to give them the width of 100% so they take up all the space next to themselves thus forcing the other element (this case the span) to be pushed down to the other line. I guess you only need to give the label 100% width but going by your code you may want to float them. In case you don't just try:

```
 label{
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[Heres a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfdq8f1c/)

**html:**

```
<div class="half">
       <label for="abc">abc</label>
         <span class="half">abcabc</span>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
 label {
       display: block;
        float: left;
        clear: left; 
    }

span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few ways you could do this. But this way comes to mind:

```
.half label, .half span {
    display:block;
}
```

***Note:*** `span` and `label` display inline by default. Which is the root cause as to why they are displaying this way. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tmp4fgw5/

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.half label, span.half { width:100%; float:left;}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwells/9mn8g4my/)

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` , `<label>`, `<a>` are default `inline` elements, which is the reason why it comes inline. So to achieve,add below CSS

```
label,span{
  display: block;
}
```